# Comment a été construite la locution « pour peu que » ?

Tags: étymologie, conjonctions, locutions

[Wiktionnaire](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pour_peu_que) :

> Quelque peu que ; si peu que.
>   — Note **[1]** : L'expression indique que seulement un petit effort, une petite contribution serait nécessaire pour atteindre l'objectif.
>   — Note d’usage **[2]** : Elle est suivie d'un verbe au subjonctif.

[TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/peu) :

> ♦ Pour peu que + verbe au subj. À la condition (si minime soit-elle) que.

Je comprends l'explication dans 1, mais comment cette acception a-t-elle été morphologiquement abrégée et condensée en la locution conjonctive  « pour peu que » ?

Ma conjecture: Peut-être « pour peu que » est un raccourci d'une expression comme « pour peu [d'effort ou de contribution] pour [effectuer] que » ?

Answer (score 1):

> Ma conjecture: Peut-être « pour peu que » est un raccourci d'une expression comme « pour peu [d'effort ou de contribution] pour [effectuer] que » ?

"Pour peu qu’il vienne, nous aurons à manger" is rather equivalent to :

- "Il suffit qu’il vienne pour que nous ayons à manger"
- "S’il vient, nous aurons à manger"
- "Si au moins il était là, nous aurions à manger"

There is an idea of a tiny contribution that may make the balance change, as you pointed.

Comment: You may also encounter : "pour autant que + subj."

Answer (score 1):

« **Pour peu que** » est une expression très ancienne en français qui signifiait à l'origine « **peu s'en faut que** », d'un hypothétique latin **pro paucum quod*.

On la retrouve sous la forme *por poi que* dans:

- la chanson de Rolland XI<sup>e</sup> siècle.

> *Et Baliganz comencet a penser,*
> *Si grant doel at **por poi qu**’il n’est desvez.*
>
> Et Baligant se mis à penser
> Si grande est la douleur, **peut s'en faut qu**'il ne perde la raison.

- Le bel inconnu, (*Li biaus descouneüs*) *Renaut de Beaujeu*, XIII<sup>e</sup> siècle

> *Adonc ot li peres tel duel*
> ***Por poi que** li cuers ne li crieve,*
>
> Alors avec le père un tel duel
> **Peut s'en faut qu**'il ne lui éclate le cœur.

Le sens a ensuite légèrement évolué pour signifier quelque chose comme « **il suffirait, même un tout petit peu, que** »

En 1694, le dictionnaire de l'Académie donne cette définition qui correspond déjà au sens que l'expression a encore aujourd'hui :

> **Pour peu que**. Façon de parler qui se construit avec le subjonctif, en plusieurs sortes de phrases. Ainsi on dit, ***Pour peu que** vous luy en parliez, il le fera*, pour dire, ***Si** vous luy en parlez **le moins du monde***.

Comment: Do you hear "pour peu que" ever used in speech today in France? If not, what is a closest modern equivalent?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens Yes, *pour peu que* is used in today's spoken French, although not in a colloquial context where *si*, *à condition* or *il suffit* might be used instead.

Comment: "*On m’a dit qu’il y avait de l’argent à se faire sur les chantiers d'Égypte, **pour peu qu**’on soit prêt à supporter la chaleur.*" If I say this, for instance, in casual conversation, do you think the use of "pour peu que" raises an eyebrow? Or is it fine?

Comment: @con-gras-tue-les-chiens I would say it's fine and never raises an eyebrow.