# Signification de "pour peu que"

Tags: sens, expressions

De l’Express:

> .. avec notre dossier de couverture, formidable galerie d’une centaine de personnalités exemplaires ... dont l’engagement au quotidien reflète une vision encourageante du monde et de la société, **pour peu que l’on œuvre à les rendre meilleurs**.

Que veut dire la portion en gras ? J'ai lu [cette question](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20148/comment-a-%C3%A9t%C3%A9-construite-la-locution-pour-peu-que) sur l'expression "pour peu que", mais je ne comprends toujours pas la phrase même si on remplace "pour peu que" par "si" ou "à condition que". Et "les" se refère-t-il à "le monde et la société" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oui, *les* représente le monde et la société.

On peut reconstruire la phrase comme ceci :

> L'engagement au quotidien d'une centaine de personnalités exemplaires dans leur œuvre à rendre meilleurs le monde et la société suffit à en donner une vision encourageante.

Comment: Je vois. Donc "l'on" dans la phrase originale se réfère à "une centaine de personnalités exemplaires" ?

Comment: Ce sont eux auxquels on pense bien sûr, mais *on* représente au sens large et de manière indéterminée toutes les personnes qui agiraient comme la centaine de personnalités.